# replacing words not letters with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace some words in a string with `.replace(desiredWord,"")`, to remove those words from that string.
 I have a string which is like this `"xsmall small medium"` and I'm trying to remove `"small"` from that string in some events, but it sometimes removes small of `xsmall` also, which is not my intention..
Is there any way to restrict replace method or I should use another method?

I want to replace or remove specific word, not letters.

Comment: Try the following: `\bsmall\b` `\b` confines the search to a word boundary.

Comment: Would simply using `string.replace(' small ', ' ')` not work, or with regex you could use `\bsmall\b`?

Comment: dude, the word that should be removed is formed by a variable I can't use reg.

Comment: no, simple .replce() does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

If you pad your `desiredWord` with the word boundary `\b` operator it will work without false positives.

```js
const sampleString = "xsmall small medium";

console.log(sampleString.replace(/\bsmall\b/g, "test"));
```

With variable

```js
document.querySelector("#replace").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
debugger
  const value = document.querySelector("#change").value;
  //escape the operators in the regexp!
  const regex = new RegExp("\\b"+value+"\\b", "g");
  document.querySelector("#text").value = document.querySelector("#text").value.replace(regex, "test");
}, true);
```

```html
<input readonly id="text" value="xsmall small medium" /><br />
<input id="change"><button id="replace">Replace</button>
```

Comment: I did this but it does not work yet===>>>let checkboxId = event.target.getAttribute('data-size');
              stringToBeSearched = stringToBeSearched.replace(`/\b${checkboxId}\b/g`, '').trim();

Comment: See the added example on how to add a variable into your regexp

Comment: Wow, that was awesome, so anytime I want to include a variable which is supposed to get regex I can use this new RegExp method, right? That was awesome and it works :) Have a great day comrade!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `RegEx` expression for this.
You can use these in the replace method directly.
A way to check this is using the next expression: `\bsmall`

The result of this is as follow :

```
string.replace(\bsmall, "")
```

`\b` will check if the characters are from 1 and only 1 word

Comment: since the word which must be removed is being formed by a variable can I just use this method for all words to define that I want a word not letters not adding \b  + to what variable gives me?

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude letters before explicitly:

```
const sampleString = "xsmall small medium";
console.log(sampleString.replace(/([^a-z])(?=small)/ig, "$1x");
```

This regular expression reads, "Not a letter, followed by (but not captured) 'small', replaced with whatever the non-letter was, followed by an x."

or the same thing using the word boundary feature, just be sure not to delete it too:

```
const sampleString = "xsmall small medium";
console.log(sampleString.replace(/(\b)(?=small)/ig, "$1x");
```

This one reads, "Any word boundary, followed by 'small' (but without 'small' forming part of the replacement), replaced by the word boundary and then an 'x'.

Comment: small comes from a variable the thing is how can I put this variable in this code instead of writing the word small...

Comment: You can construct the regular expression using a string, including variable interpolation, e.g. something like `.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(?=${varName})`, 'ig'), "$1x");`